# Openshift REST endpoint model jars

Tags: java, spring-boot, openshift, redhat, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to call the REST endpoints Redhat openshift exposes from my Java application to get list of deployments in a namespace.

```
GET /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/$NAMESPACE/deployments HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN
Accept: application/json
Connection: close
```

I created the model Java class corresponding to the response this endpoint return, only manually. I hardcoded the bearer token in the HTTP header and invoked the rest end point in java to get the list of deployments. After i get the response, I parsed the response into these model classes i created.

Question 1:

Is there a place i can get the jars corresponding to the response objects which i can directly import in my java code instead of manually creating the response models and parsing the response json into these models?

Question 2:

What is the Openshift REST endpoint to retrieve the Bearer token.

Answer (score 0):

When interacting with Kubernetes / OpenShift from Java, I would recommend to use the Java Kubernetes Client: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java

You can also find [examples](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/Example.java) on how to use the Java API in the repository:

```java
[..]

public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ApiException {
    ApiClient client = Config.defaultClient();
    Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);

    CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api();
    V1PodList list =
        api.listPodForAllNamespaces(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    for (V1Pod item : list.getItems()) {
      System.out.println(item.getMetadata().getName());
    }
  }
}
```

When using the above library, getting a Bearer token is not necessary, as this is all handled by the client.

Nevertheless, OpenShift [implements OAuth](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/additional_concepts/authentication.html#oauth), this means you can query the OpenShift OAuth server using the standard OAuth endpoints.

If you want to use a `ServiceAccount` from an external source, you can find the description on how to get the token [in the documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/service_accounts.html#using-a-service-accounts-credentials-externally):

```
$ oc describe secret robot-token-uzkbh -n top-secret
Name:       robot-token-uzkbh
Labels:     <none>
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/service-account.name=robot,kubernetes.io/service-account.uid=49f19e2e-16c6-11e5-afdc-3c970e4b7ffe

Type:   kubernetes.io/service-account-token

Data

token:  eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9...
[..]
```